# html.checkbox - explicit value to hidden field value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am creating list of checkboxes in partial view by follwoing http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

code and Rendered HTML for checkboxes is as follows

```
  <%=Html.CheckBox("EmployeeID", new { value = user.EmployeeID, @class = "ccboxes", title = user.Designation + "(" + user.EmployeeName + ")" })%>

<INPUT id=MemoUsers_a29f82e4-ebbc-47b0-8cdd-7d54f94143be__EmployeeID class=boxes title=Programmer(Zia) value=6 type=checkbox name=MemoUsers[a29f82e4-ebbc-47b0-8cdd-7d54f94143be].EmployeeID jQuery1276681299292="27">

<INPUT value=false type=hidden name=MemoUsers[a29f82e4-ebbc-47b0-8cdd-7d54f94143be].EmployeeID>
```

In rendered html it can be seen that value attribute of hidden field is false. i want to assign explicit value(same as checkbox value) to this value. Is this possible using html.checkbox or html.checkboxfor.

one way is recommended in http:[//stackoverflow.com/questions/626901/asp-net-mvc-rc2-checkboxes-with-explicit-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626901/asp-net-mvc-rc2-checkboxes-with-explicit-values). Is there any other better way

i want to do this as ModelState.IsValid is returning false because of hidden field value attribute

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the default Html helper will not allow you to do that. Either you build your own Html helper or render the checkbox manually should get what you want.